# gitlab ci yml image and services mechanism?

Tags: image, docker, service, yaml, gitlab-ci

I don't understand the mechanism of the keywords `image` and `services` in the file.gitlab-ci.yml. when do we know on which image the commands of the keyword `script` are executed ?

When i read the gitlabci documentation i understand the theory of the keywords "image" and "services" well, so i have already done tests and managed to interact with a `httpd` service by a wget for example, however, in practice i can't understand what the image is for ?

Let me explain :)

First i created a structure with a job that makes a "uname -a" by not declaring any images:

```
job_scriptWithDefaultImage:
  stage: gitlabtest1
  script:
    - uname -a
```

The result then shows me a "uname -a" running on the runner:

```
$ uname -a
Linux runner-b41b332f-project-9060-concurrent-0 4.4.0-104-generic #127-Ubuntu SMP Mon Dec 11 12:16:42 UTC 2017 x86_64 Linux
```

Then i simply add an image in my job specifying i want to use an alpine:

```
job_scriptWithAlpineImage:
  internship: gitlabtest2
  image: registry.hub.docker.com/library/alpine:latest
  script:
    - uname -a
```

The result is exactly the same, the uname always runs on the runner, instead of my alpine ...

```
$ uname -a
Linux runner-9cade5e3-project-9060-concurrent-0 4.4.0-130-generic #156-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jun 14 08:53:28 UTC 2018 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

So i don't understand at all:

- What my image is for ?
- How to execute commands in that image in my pipeline job `script` section ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker uses the host's kernel. As you can see by your `uname -a` output, it gives the runner's machine info. That's why regardless of the container you get the same output. You can even try it on your machine.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/31012367/4551937

Regarding Gitlab Runner, your `service` is independent. It will be attached and provided to your job calling it, as if it was running beside it.

Your job will use the image you specify with the `image` tag to run the commands listed in `script` (you can chain them). If no image is specified, it will take the default one defined in the runner configuration (probably Ubuntu).

Comment: Do I understand that any command found on the host (runner) will be used instead of the image one, is there a notion of priority ?

For example, if I do a uname -a, it is the runner who answers as you explain it, however if I do an apt update, then it is on the image that the command is executed.

How do I know for sure that the command I launch is launched from the image and not from the host ?

Is there a system command list,  or should I blindly trust the dock runner and tell myself that as long as it works I have nothing more to understand ? how lucky we are :)

Comment: That's not the runner answering, that's the container, but reading the runner's kernel. The docker runner has a set config, it's either a docker runner, or a shell one (default to the first if I remember, there might have been an hybrid mode but I think they dropped it). You don't need to "trust" anything, because it will do what you configured it to do ;) Also: don't run `apt-get` in your container if you can avoid it, you will be wasting time every time you run your job. Just build a cached image with per-installed dependencies.

Comment: Okay, thanks, I understand a lot better now ! (apt update was just there for the example). I did some more tests following your answer, I finally understood who was launching what and in what order :) Thank you for unlocking my understanding, too bad the documentation is not as accurate as your answers:)