# Using Ubuntu 14.04 docker for cross compilation

Tags: linux, docker, cross-compiling

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 docker in Ubuntu 18.04. From inside Ubuntu 14.04 docker if I run "uname -r" command then it is showing same output, when I ran the same command in Ubuntu 18.04.
I want to use Ubuntu 14.04 to cross compile package for the target, but at the beginning of configuration, it is checking for confiuration and it is failing with the following error.

```
checking for the kernel version... unsupported (5.4.0-generic)
configure: error: Valgrind works on kernel 2.4, 2.6
```

Comment: docker works on top of kernel

Comment: A Docker container shares the host's kernel, and `uname -r` will report the same value inside or outside a container ([$(uname -a) returning the same in docker host or any docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31012297/uname-a-returning-the-same-in-docker-host-or-any-docker-container)).  You may need a VM with an isolated kernel for this to work.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I have very little idea about cross compilation, any specific reason why the cross compilation process depends on host PC kernel version. can you provide any references to understand this more.